# Create a matrix with gradually changing values without a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, vector, s

In R, I am building a matrix `M` that stores 4 changing weights for each of 20 rounds of a game.

I start with the weight vector `W1` (4x1) and end game with weight vector `W2` (4x1).

The weight values remain constant until the change initiation round `C1` (=5).

After the round `C1` the weights start mutating by equal increments `w2c` and `w3c` over `C` (=10) rounds.

The weights have to always add to `1`.

I used a `for` loop to build a matrix `M`. The result looks like this:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,] 0.30 0.50 0.10 0.10
 [2,] 0.30 0.50 0.10 0.10
 [3,] 0.30 0.50 0.10 0.10
 [4,] 0.30 0.50 0.10 0.10
 [5,] 0.30 0.50 0.10 0.10
 [6,] 0.28 0.46 0.12 0.14
 [7,] 0.26 0.42 0.14 0.18
 [8,] 0.24 0.38 0.16 0.22
 [9,] 0.22 0.34 0.18 0.26
[10,] 0.20 0.30 0.20 0.30
[11,] 0.18 0.26 0.22 0.34
[12,] 0.16 0.22 0.24 0.38
[13,] 0.14 0.18 0.26 0.42
[14,] 0.12 0.14 0.28 0.46
[15,] 0.10 0.10 0.30 0.50
[16,] 0.10 0.10 0.30 0.50
[17,] 0.10 0.10 0.30 0.50
[18,] 0.10 0.10 0.30 0.50
[19,] 0.10 0.10 0.30 0.50
[20,] 0.10 0.10 0.30 0.50
```

Here is my R code:

Inputs:

```
N=4 # 4 number of weights
R=20 #rounds
M <- matrix(0, ncol=N, nrow=R) 
C=10 # change duration in rounds
C1=5 # round at which change starts
C2=C1+C # round at which change ends
w1=0.1 #small weight
w2=0.3 #average weight
w3=0.5 #large weight
w2c=(w2-w1)/C #change increment for average weight mutation
w3c=(w3-w1)/C #change increment for large weight mutation
W1<-c(w2, w3, w1, w1) #starting weight vector
W2<-c(w1, w1, w2, w3) #ending weight vector
```

For loop, building the matrix `M`:

```
for(n in 1:N){
  M[,n]<-W1[n]
  for(r in 1:R) {
    if(r>=C2){M[r,n] <- W2[n]}
  }
}

for(r in C1:(C2-1)) {
  T<-r-C1;
  M[r,1] =  M[r,1]-w2c*T;
  M[r,2] =  M[r,2]-w3c*T;
  M[r,3] =  M[r,3]+w2c*T;
  M[r,4] =  M[r,4]+w3c*T;
}
M
```

Is there a more efficient way to achieve the same result without a `for` loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three calls to fill the top, middle, and bottom respectively:

```
M[1:C1,  ] <- rep(W1, each = C1)
M[C1:C2, ] <- mapply(seq, from = W1, to = W2, length = C2 - C1 + 1)
M[C2:R,  ] <- rep(W2, each = R - C2 + 1)
```

If like me you like code that is very symmetric (or consistent), you can generalize and say that the top and bottom parts are like the middle one: they are linearly moving from `W1` to `W1` and from `W2` to `W2` respectively. Hence:

```
M[1:C1,  ] <- mapply(seq, from = W1, to = W1, length = C1 -  1 + 1)
M[C1:C2, ] <- mapply(seq, from = W1, to = W2, length = C2 - C1 + 1)
M[C2:R,  ] <- mapply(seq, from = W2, to = W2, length =  R - C2 + 1)
```

Comment: I appreciate the symmetry and the visual clarity of your solution. Especially, since it does not need to be modified if the `W1` and `W2` length or other values change (e.g. R, C, C1).

Answer (score 2):

You can do a vectorised multiplication of your weights by the number of change time steps, and then add these vectors to the pre-change values (e.g. with `sweep`).

```
x <- rbind(c(0.30, 0.50, 0.10, 0.10))
M <- rbind(x[rep(1, C1), ],
           sweep( sapply(c(-w2c, -w3c, w2c, w3c), '*', seq_len(C)),
                    2, x, '+'))
M <- rbind(M, M[ nrow(M), , drop=FALSE][ rep(1, R-C1-C), ])

#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#  [1,] 0.30 0.50 0.10 0.10
#  [2,] 0.30 0.50 0.10 0.10
#  [3,] 0.30 0.50 0.10 0.10
#  [4,] 0.30 0.50 0.10 0.10
#  [5,] 0.30 0.50 0.10 0.10
#  [6,] 0.28 0.46 0.12 0.14
#  [7,] 0.26 0.42 0.14 0.18
#  [8,] 0.24 0.38 0.16 0.22
#  [9,] 0.22 0.34 0.18 0.26
# [10,] 0.20 0.30 0.20 0.30
# [11,] 0.18 0.26 0.22 0.34
# [12,] 0.16 0.22 0.24 0.38
# [13,] 0.14 0.18 0.26 0.42
# [14,] 0.12 0.14 0.28 0.46
# [15,] 0.10 0.10 0.30 0.50
# [16,] 0.10 0.10 0.30 0.50
# [17,] 0.10 0.10 0.30 0.50
# [18,] 0.10 0.10 0.30 0.50
# [19,] 0.10 0.10 0.30 0.50
# [20,] 0.10 0.10 0.30 0.50
```

Comment: Hope you don't mind the formatting edits. I had trouble mentally parsing the original. Quite a nice answer. I suppose a `Reduce( . , . )` strategy that returned an `rbind()`-ed result could work, but I doubt it would improve clarity or performance.

Comment: @jbaums, it is a very nice solution! The only reason I prefer the answer by @flodel, is the ease by which I can extend it to more complicated scenarios. For instance, if we add a 5th weight (5th column in M) that remains constant over R rounds, as far as I understand, the code should be modified in the following way: 
`x <- rbind(c(0.30, 0.50, 0.1,0.1, 0.1, 0.1));`
`M <- rbind(x[rep(1, C1), ], sweep( sapply(c(-w2c, -w3c, w2c, w3c, 0), '*', seq_len(C)), 2, x, '+'));`
`M <- rbind(M, M[ nrow(M), , drop=FALSE][ rep(1, R-C1-C), ])`

Comment: @inarts - of course, no problem. I prefer flodel's answer as well! I didn't realise we had the ending weights at our disposal. And yes, your modification would be correct. :)